# How to load data from sql through ajax using php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

My HTML/PHP code:

```
<br/><br/><div id="dialog-modal"></div><br/><br/>

<?php foreach (range(0, 29) as $rs) { ?>
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#" data-href="rsc1<?php echo $rs;?>" class="link">pvz - rsc1<?php echo $rs;?></a><br/>
<?php } ?>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
$('.link').on('click',function(e){
var linkValue = $(this).attr('data-href');
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    //url: 'details.php',
    //data: 'i=' + linkValue,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.ui-dialog-title').html(linkValue)
        $('#dialog-modal').html(linkValue).dialog();
    }

}); 
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

The `details.php` code:

```
$i = $_GET['i'];
echo $i;
```

This script opens only new dialog with my sent data from url `data-href`. All I want to do is to take some data from sql db into that dialog window by variable `$i`…

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know how to get data from sql database and show it in your ajax response.
If so then try something like this:

**details.php code:**

```
 $i = $_GET['i'];//getting your data
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "db name");//set your correct database connection string
   //check if connection errors 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
   //make  a query with valid table name   
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from your_table ");
    if($result->num_rows){ //check if any data found
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo  $row['id'];// echo this data
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "no data found!";//echo no data found
    }

    mysqli_close($link); // close mysql connection
```

In this php page what ever i have echoed it will send as ajax response in your success call back's data. that will display in your modal. I just tried to give you a basic idea. I think it will help you.

Some good resource links: http://www.phptutorialforbeginners.com/2013/01/jquery-ajax-tutorial-and-example-of.html
http://www.cleverweb.nl/php/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial/

Comment: @dehood : did you want something like this or anything else?

Comment: thanks for links, i will check them later, but i want to put some data from sql into dialog window, when clicked on url. i have done that but output shows just text.. i want to make that text would be variable.. you can check my script http://dehood.lt/project/test/testas.php